# web.py class importing error

Tags: python, web.py

Here is my index.py (it is in the folder /NetWeave_Custom)

```
import web
import lib.html

web.config.debug = True

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        markup = html.abstr()
        print markup.element

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

And then here is my html.py (it is in /NetWeave_Custom/lib/)

```
class abstr:
    element = 'Hello World';
```

However I am getting a 500 internal server error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to the web.py framework. Thanks!

EDIT:

With the code above I get the errror:
ImportError: no module named lib.html

FINAL EDIT:

Working code looked like this:

```
import web
from lib import html

web.config.debug = True

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        markup = html.abstr()
        return markup.element

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
    app.run()

application = app.wsgifunc()
```

And then here is my html.py (it is in /NetWeave_Custom/lib/)

```
class abstr:
    element = 'Hello World';
```

The browser displayed: 'Hello World'
So the changes were defining app before calling it (not really relevant but for you stricties it is necessary -- it did work fine without this), returning markup.element rather than printing it, and creating a blank `__init__.py` file in the lib subdirectory so lib would be viewed as a module (or package?) as I understand it.

Thanks!

Comment: Any stack trace to go with 500? Would help determining the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the server as well. Is that in one of the log files?

Comment: IF you have logfiles, yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was two-fold. I did not have an `__init__.py` file in the lib sub-directory. The other error was that I wrote `print` and not `return markup.element`... Doh!

Answer (score 1):

You import `lib.html`, but don't use that full name. Instead, you refer only to `html`.

If you get an import error, the `lib` package is not being found; there may be one of two things wrong:

- You should use `import html` instead, which would also solve the incorrect reference.
- The `lib` directory is missing it's `__init__.py` file (can be empty). That file would make it a package and would allow you to import it. Then change the references to `html` to `lib.html`:

  ```
  class index:
      def GET(self):
          markup = lib.html.abstr()
          print markup.element
  ```

  *or* change the import to read:

  ```
  from lib import html
  ```

You also try to run `app` before it is defined. Change the last lines to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
    app.run()
```

Last but not least, you need to add the `NetWeave_Custom` directory (full, absolute path) to the `PYTHONPATH`; if you are using `mod_wsgi` look at the [`WSGIPythonPath`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonPath) directive.

Comment: Are you sure I don't need to reference it specially because it is in a subfolder?

Comment: If `lib` is a subfolder, then it needs a `__init__.py` file to mark it a package. A directory *without* that file cannot be used to import from unless it is specifically added to the python module search path (`sys.path`).

Comment: I did that but it still shot an error, does the html.py module need to be formatted using the web.py framework?

Comment: @phileaton: What is the error? Please add that to your question, we are just guessing here without the *full* traceback.

Comment: It says no module named lib

Comment: @phileaton: So a file `test.py` with the contents `from lib import html` in the directory `NetWeave_Custom`, then running `test.py` gives you the error `ImportError: No module named lib`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21779/discussion-between-martijn-pieters-and-phileaton)